# How can I check the file extensions in c?

Tags: c, arrays, char

I'm struggling with this for several days now.

I want to create a functions that goes through a directory, pick all the files with an extension *.csv and read the data in them.

I created a function that is supposed to check each file name that is legal, by checking that the string ends with .csv. To do this, I want to go to the end of the char * array. I tried this:

```
 char * point = file_name;
 while (point != "\0"){
    point += 1;
 }
```

which goes through the char * array without finding and "\0".

If I write

```
*point != "\0"
```

The compiler warns me that I'm comparing and int to a char.

I should note that I get the filename using

```
 dirent->d_name
```

Comment: Actually, `"\0"` is the memory address of a string literal that will be stored elsewhere during runtime.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`point != "\0"` compares a pointer to another pointer, which is not what you want.

You want to compare whatever `point` points to , to a char with the value 0. So use e.g.

```
*point != '\0';
```

Note, if you want to find the end of the string, you could also do

```
point = file_name + strlen(filename);
```

If you want to check whether a string ends in .csv, you could also do something like

```
if((point = strrchr(filename,'.')) != NULL ) {
     if(strcmp(point,".csv") == 0) {
          //ends with csv
      }
  }
```

EDIT : fixed formatting

Comment: I'm pretty sure that d_name is 256 chars long, will strlen work in that case as well?

Answer (score 9):

You must dereference the pointer to look at the value it points at:

```
while (*point != '\0')
  point++;
```

Note that the right hand side is a character literal (single quotes), not a string (double quotes). This fixes the warning you got when trying to use a string.

Also note that it's really unnecessary to find the end of the string to check this. A better approach would be:

```
int ends_with(const char* name, const char* extension, size_t length)
{
  const char* ldot = strrchr(name, '.');
  if (ldot != NULL)
  {
    if (length == 0)
      length = strlen(extension);
    return strncmp(ldot + 1, extension, length) == 0;
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Call the above with e.g. ends_with("test.foo", "foo", 3) and you will get 1 returned, if no match is found it returns 0.

This is not faster, but it's a lot clearer since it operates at a higher level, using only well-known standard string functions.

Comment: Instead of looking for a suffix hardcodededly delimted by a '.' I'd supply that period as part of the "extension" parameter. This is more flexible.

Comment: The reason I'm searching for the end of the file is to avoid the *.old which linux users are fond of.

Answer (score 3):

To get the extension from a file name you can use the [`strrchr`](http://www.manpagez.com/man/3/strchr/) function to get the position of the last occurrence of a character in a string:

```
char * end = strrchr(filename, '.');
if(strcmp(end, ".csv") == 0)
{
    // Yuppee! A CSV file! Let's do something with it!
}
```

(And have a look at what others have said, as they address several problems with your code.)

Answer (score 1):

unwind is right, you just interpreted his code wrong.
What many (especially newbies; don't want to call you such) don't notice (especially when coming from other languages like JavaScript or PHP) is, that "" and '' aren't the same in C++. (Neither are they in PHP but the difference is bigger here.)

`"a"` is a string - essentially a `const char[2]`.
`'a'` is a single char - it's just a `char`.

What you want is comparing a single character to a single character, so you have to use `'\0'`.
If you use `"\0"` you essentially compare your character to the address of the essentially empty string (which is an integer).

Comment: Nothing to be ashamed of, I'm a newbie to c.

Answer (score 0):

Try single quotes not double quotes.  This limits the constant to a character.  Double quotes are for strings not characters.  You need to dereference point using * to get to the character:

```
 char * point = file_name;
 while (*point != '\0')
    ++point;
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on @unwind's answer, I propose this version to check if a `name` ends with a specific `extension`. Note that the inputs are declared as const pointers pointing to `const char`.

```
int stringEndsWith(
        char const * const name,
        char const * const extension)
{
    size_t length = 0;
    char* ldot = NULL;
    if (name == NULL) return 0;
    if (extension == NULL) return 0;
    length = strlen(extension);
    if (length == 0) return 0;
    ldot = strrchr(name, extension[0]);
    if (ldot != NULL)
    {
        return (strncmp(ldot, extension, length) == 0);
    }
    return 0;
}
```